# Convert to Array or Collection or List

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a big chunk of data in this format:

```json
 [
    {"date":"2018-11-17"},{"weather":"sunny"},{"Temp":"9"},
    {"date":"2014-12-19"},{"Temp":"10"},{"weather":"rainy"},
    {"date":"2018-04-10"},{"weather":"cloudy"},{"Temp":"15"},
    {"date":"2017-01-28"},{"weather":"sunny"},{"Temp":"12"}
 ]
```

Is there any faster and more efficient way to organize and save it the database for future reference? Like making a comparison of the temperature for different days etc. `[date,weather,Temp]` are supposed to be in one set.

I've tried `str_replace()` but I'd like to know if there's any better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account your comment, it seems that is an array of objects in which *every three objects* make a record (that is form of: `date`, `weather` & `temp`) so you can create this setup with the help of collections:

```
$string = ['your', 'json', 'string'];
$records = collect(json_decode($string))
               ->chunk(3) // this creates a subset of every three items
               ->mapSpread(function ($date, $weather, $temp) { // this will map them
                   return array_merge((array) $date, (array) $weather, (array) $temp);
               });
```

This will give you this output:

```
dd($records);
```

> ```
> => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3465
>      all: [
>        [
>          "date" => "2018-11-17",
>          "weather" => "sunny",
>          "Temp" => "9",
>        ],
>        [
>          "date" => "2014-12-19",
>          "Temp" => "10",
>          "weather" => "rainy",
>        ],
>        [
>          "date" => "2018-04-10",
>          "weather" => "cloudy",
>          "Temp" => "15",
>        ],
>        [
>          "date" => "2017-01-28",
>          "weather" => "sunny",
>          "Temp" => "12",
>        ],
>      ],
>    }
> ```

PS: To get the array version of this collections just attach `->all()` at the end.

---

You can check in the [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections) documentation a good explanation of the [`chunk()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-chunk) and [`mapSpread()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-mapspread) methods as well of the rest of the [available methods](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#available-methods).

Comment: Too bad the string is as I mentioned above, with square brackets only at the beginning and at the end.